# Compiler errors - out of ideas

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, char

So I've been trying to make this work for days now, but to no avail.

I have this hpp file (Tree.hpp):

```
#ifndef _TREE_H    
#define _TREE_H   

#include <cstdlib>    
#include <string>    
#include <algorithm>    
#include <list>    
#include <vector>    
#include <cstring>    
#include <sstream>    
#include <iostream>

// tree of characters, can be used to implement a trie  

template <class T>    

class Tree {    

  friend class TreeTempTest;    
  T *data;     // the value stored in the tree node    
  T * kids;  // children - pointer to first child of list, maintain order & uniqueness
  T * sibs;  // siblings - pointer to rest of children list, maintain order & uniqueness   
  // this should always be null if the object is the root of a tree

  T * prev;  // pointer to parent if this is a first child, or left sibling otherwise

  // this should always be null if the object is the root of a tree

public:   

  Tree(T ch);
  Tree(T ch, T *kidsVal, T *sibsVal, T *prevVal);
  ~Tree();  // clear siblings to right and children and this node    
  //CTree(CTree *tree); //Deep copy
  //bool operator== (const CTree &tree); 

  // siblings and children must be unique, return true if added, false otherwise

  bool addChild(T ch);    
  // add tree root for better building, root should have null prev and sibs 

  // returns false on any type of failure, including invalid root

  bool addChild(Tree<T> *root);   
  std::string toString() const; // all characters, separated by newlines, including at the end    
  //bool removeChild(char c);    

private:    

  // these should only be called from addChild, and have the same restrictions

  // the root of a tree should never have any siblings

  // returns false on any type of failure, including invalid root

  bool addSibling(T ch);   
  bool addSibling(Tree<T> *root);


} ;    

template <class T>    
Tree<T>::Tree(T ch) : kids(NULL), sibs(NULL), prev(NULL) {    
  data = &ch;
}    

template <class T>    
Tree<T>::Tree(T ch, T *kidsVal, T *sibsVal, T *prevVal) {   
  data = &ch;    
  kids = kidsVal;    
  sibs = sibsVal;
  prev = prevVal;    
}    

// copy constructor?  extra credit    
template <class T>    
Tree<T>:: ~Tree() {    
    delete kids;   // will call destructor on first child and recurse?    
    delete sibs;   // will call destructor on first sibling and recurse?    
  prev = NULL;    
}   

// siblings and children must be unique, return true if added, false otherwise    
template <class T>    
bool Tree<T>:: addChild(T ch) {    
  if (!kids) {    
    kids = new T(ch);    
    kids->prev = this;
    return true;    
  }

  else if (! (kids->data == ch))    
    return (kids->addSibling(ch));    
  else    
    return false;    
}   

// siblings and children must be unique, return true if added, false otherwise

template <class T>    
bool Tree<T>:: addChild(Tree<T> *root) {    
  if (!root || root->prev || root->sibs) {    
    return false;  // is invalid or null root    
  }

  if (!kids) {    
    kids = root;    
    root->prev = this;    
    return true;    
  }

  else if (! (kids->data == root->data))    
    return kids->addSibling(root);    
  else    
    return false;    
}



template <class T>    
bool Tree<T>::addSibling(T ch) {    
  T *root = new T(ch);    
  bool added = addSibling(root);    
  if (! added)  // clean up memory    
    delete root;    
  return added;    
}



template <class T>    
bool Tree<T>::addSibling(Tree<T> *root) {    
  if (!root || root->prev || root->sibs || !prev) {    
    return false;  // is invalid or null root    
  }

  if (data == root->data) {  // can't add if same node data    
    return false;    
  }

  if (root->data < this->data) {  // insert before this    
    root->sibs = this;    
    root->prev = this->prev;    
    if (this->prev->kids == this) {  // this was first child    
        prev->kids = root;  // new first child for parent    
    }

    this->prev = root;    
    return true;

  }

  if (! sibs || root->data < sibs->data)  { // insert between this and sibs

    root->prev = this;    
    root->sibs = sibs;
        if (sibs) {    
      sibs->prev = root;    
    }

    this->sibs = root;    
    return true;    
  }

  if (sibs) {  // root->data > sibs->data, so recurse    
    return sibs->addSibling(root);    
  }

  std::cerr << "bad end to addSibling" << std::endl;

  return false;  // shouldn't get here

}



// need depth-first toString    
template <class T>    
std::string Tree<T>::toString() const {    
  std::string vals = "";    
  std::ostringstream oss;    
  oss << data << std::endl;    
  vals = oss.str();    
  if (kids)    
    vals += kids->toString();    
  if (sibs)    
    vals += sibs->toString();

  return vals;

}


#endif
```

This is part of my test file (TreeTempTest.cpp). The errors are thrown at the very first assert statement.

```
#include "Tree.hpp"
#include "FileDir.h"
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <vector>


using std::cout;
using std::endl;

using namespace std;

class TreeTempTest {
public:

    static void constructorTest() {
        // build a few trees with constructor
        //char trees
        Tree <char> t1('A');
        assert(t1.toString() == "A\n");
```

... There are a lot more lines of code in the test file, but they are not pertinent to this problem perhaps.

And these are the dreaded errors:

```
 Tree.hpp: In instantiation of ‘std::string Tree<T>::toString() const [with T = char; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’:
    TreeTempTest.cpp:35:9:   required from here
    Tree.hpp:179:10: error: request for member ‘toString’ in ‘*(char*)((const Tree<char>*)this)->Tree<char>::kids’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
         vals += kids->toString();
              ^
    Tree.hpp:181:10: error: request for member ‘toString’ in ‘*(char*)((const Tree<char>*)this)->Tree<char>::sibs’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
         vals += sibs->toString();
              ^
    Tree.hpp: In instantiation of ‘std::string Tree<T>::toString() const [with T = std::basic_string<char>; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’:
    TreeTempTest.cpp:46:9:   required from here
    Tree.hpp:179:10: error: ‘class std::basic_string<char>’ has no member named ‘toString’
         vals += kids->toString();
              ^
    Tree.hpp:181:10: error: ‘class std::basic_string<char>’ has no member named ‘toString’
         vals += sibs->toString();
              ^
    Tree.hpp: In instantiation of ‘std::string Tree<T>::toString() const [with T = int; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’:
    TreeTempTest.cpp:58:9:   required from here
    Tree.hpp:179:10: error: request for member ‘toString’ in ‘*(int*)((const Tree<int>*)this)->Tree<int>::kids’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
         vals += kids->toString();
              ^
    Tree.hpp:181:10: error: request for member ‘toString’ in ‘*(int*)((const Tree<int>*)this)->Tree<int>::sibs’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
         vals += sibs->toString();
              ^
    Tree.hpp: In instantiation of ‘bool Tree<T>::addChild(T) [with T = char]’:
    TreeTempTest.cpp:91:9:   required from here
    Tree.hpp:103:16: error: request for member ‘prev’ in ‘*((Tree<char>*)this)->Tree<char>::kids’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
         kids->prev = this;
                    ^
    Tree.hpp:106:26: error: request for member ‘data’ in ‘*((Tree<char>*)this)->Tree<char>::kids’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
       else if (! (kids->data == ch))
                              ^
    Tree.hpp:107:33: error: request for member ‘addSibling’ in ‘*((Tree<char>*)this)->Tree<char>::kids’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
         return (kids->addSibling(ch));
                                     ^
    Tree.hpp: In instantiation of ‘bool Tree<T>::addSibling(T) [with T = char]’:
    TreeTempTest.cpp:120:9:   required from here
    :
```

Can't figure out what is causing the errors.

Comment: Which line is `Tree.hpp:179`?

Comment: @DrewDormann   vals += kids->toString();

Comment: For reference: #endif is at the 185th line.

Comment: Note that `_TREE_H` is formally invalid since identifiers starting with underscore followed by uppercase letter are reserved to the implementation. Also note that the first error message says exactly what's wrong with that line, namely how it parses the expression (you evidently thought it would parse differently). Fix the first error, rebuild, then fix the new first error, and so on.

Comment: Tree.hpp compiles. TreeTempTest.cpp doesn't,

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It should not parse this way. Don't know why it is.

Comment: Seems like `Tree<char>` makes `kids` and `sibs` `char*`, not `Tree*` as it seems like you assume.

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace: Oh, thanks! I didn't think enough, just seemed "obvious".

Comment: Don't write so much code at once...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line:

```
vals += kids->toString();
```

`kids` is declared as `T*`, or in your case `char *`. `char*` is not a pointer to a class, and it certainly does not have a `toString` function.

Comment: So should kids be Tree*?

Comment: If you're trying to implement a tree in the datastructure sense, then it's a good idea to make all nodes in the tree have the same type.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class T>    
Tree<T>::Tree(T ch) : kids(NULL), sibs(NULL), prev(NULL) {    
  data = &ch;   <<<<<<<<
}
```

This is never going to work. You're trying to take the address of a parameter that's been passed by value.

Comment: to clarify: the code is legal and won't raise any error messages, but it will cause undefined behaviour to try and use `data` after that